# Integral of a function defined on dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, intuition

**[Edited]**

For a real-valued continuous function $f$ defined on a Lebesgue measurable dense subset of $[0,2]$, consider an integral
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\frac{f(s)}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds.
$$

**My question is whether this integral can be determined or not.**

Here the integral is handled in the sense of Lebesgue integral.
For the reason, if the kernel, namely the denominator of integrand does not appear, then it is clear that this is determined.
However, this has a singularity, i.e, improper integral and so I'm confusing.
For example, I'm wondering how I should consider them when $f$ is not defined at $s=1$.

If some conditions are needed to determine this integral, I'm glad if you show for me.

In addition, since I don't understand a difference of integrals for between discontinuous functions and functions defined on dense subset, I'm great happy if you teach me if possible.

Thank you in advance

---

**[Motivation]**

*This involves my future work.

For a upper semicontinuous function $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$, I want to interpret the following integral in a weak sense in the below way
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\frac{f'(s)}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds.
$$

1. Consider the subdifferential $D^{+}f(t)$ for $t\in[0,2]$.
2. Define a function $g:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(t)=a\in D^{+}f(t)$.
3. Interpret the above integral as
   $$
   \int_{[0,1]}\frac{g(s)}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds
   $$

Now, there are some problems:

1. $D^{+}f$ is dense in $[0,2]$ but is possibly empty and multivalued.
2. Thus $g$ may not be defined at some points.

Please temporally assume conditions written in the beginning.

Comment: There is a problem: the dense subset, which is the domain of $f$, may not be Lebesgue measurable. In such a case, the integral is not even defined.

Comment: even if $f$ is defined on the whole interval and there is no denominator, the integral need not exist. Do you assume that $f$ is measurable, what else do you assume?

Comment: Why do you want a dense set?

Comment: Maybe by "functions defined on a dense subset" you are talknig about "functions defined almost everywhere"? These two concepts are not equivalent.

Comment: @Crostul Yes, I know that. I forget to write it and please think that it is assumed.

Comment: you may edit your question to bring it in the form when it is clearly stated (so one would not need to read all comments).

Comment: @Mirko I'm sorry not to write the detail. To find such condition is also one of my aim but please think it is assumed. (Yes, I'll edit soon)

Comment: @mlainz Ok, I'll add my motivation of this question.

Comment: @user notice that a density does not play well with measure. $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $1_{{\mathbb{Q}}^c}$ are both defined on a dense subset but $\int_{[0,1]} 1_{\mathbb{Q}} = 0 \neq \int_{[0,1]} 1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}=1$. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @mlainz I don't realize such relationship although I know that the integral of $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is so. Thank you for nice information.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of measure? Lebesgue integration theory does not distinguish between functions which are different on a set of measure 0. In particular, countable sets have measure 0.

Comment: 1 and $1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}$ can be thought as the same function (in Lebesgue theory), and give always the same result when integrated.

Comment: @mlainz I have studied in a general way and so I know that. But honestly I'm not familiar and I don't understand accurately a relationship between density and Lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: @user how big can the set in which $D^+f(t)$ is not a number be?

Comment: @mlainz I define it by a set of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(s)\le f(t)+a(s-t)+o(|t-s|)$ as $s\to t$. So, $D^{+}f$ may be unbounded but does not include $\{\pm\infty\}$.

Comment: @user the problem is in the domain. You can make sense of the integral if the set in which you have problems has measure 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37788/discussion-between-user-and-mlainz).